# Is There any way to share SQL Server 2008 Diagrams

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any way we can share the SQL Server 2008 database Diagram (Other then capturing the jpeg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the 2005 version of this [tool](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008/) which did the job very nicely.

EDIT: The original link is dead.  However http://devnuggets.blogspot.com/2011/04/script-diagram-really.html seems to be the same person's code for scripting/moving diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server 2008 diagrams are stored in a sysdiagram table in the same database as a binary value.
We can copy the binary data and then reinsert them at another databse to recreate them there. But the table structure of the database needs to be there as well. So in this case it is of no important use for sharing.